# How do you vertically align UILabel text to the top now that sizeWithFront is deprecated? ios7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uilabel, vertical-alignment

It's been EXTREMELY frustrating trying to vertically align UILabel text to the top. I've search google for hours, and everything I've found has been deprecated.

What is the best way to do this? I've used numberOfLines=0 & sizeToFit... but this doesn't work upon initial loading of the UILabel on a custom TVCell.

Does anyone have a code snippet that works for align UILabel text to the top on a custom cell?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate height of text and set `UILabel` frame again.

try this-

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);
CGSize labelSize = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize 
                                      options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine|NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                      attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                      context:nil].size;
[label setFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x, label.frame.origin.y, label.frame.size.width, labelSize.height)];
```